# Plotting single point for scatter using custom legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a custom scatter legend. I want it to show a single point in the legend, so I am using `scatterpoints=1`. However it still plots 2-points and a line between them.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
markers = ['^', 's']
legend_elements=[Line2D([0], [0], marker=m, label=str(t)) for m,t in zip(markers,[1,2])]
plt.legend(handles=legend_elements, scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

This is the result I get.

[image]

I suspect that the problem is caused because I use `Line2D`, but I can't find another object to create the legend.

I am following instructions from: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html

**Environment**

- CentOS 7
- matplotlib 1.5.0
- Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)

Comment: @Mr.T I am using a much older version of matiplotlib, 1.5. :/

Comment: Have you tried `numpoints=1` instead of scatterpoints? Not sure what works with 1.5/2.7 though.

Comment: Oh yeah, that works. I had to add `linestyle=''` to the Line2D and `numpoints=1` to `plt.legend`.